# How to change the quantity in a stock control in Python that uses an Excel spreadsheet as a database?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm studying Python 3 and I was testing what I learned and decided to do a simple inventory control, only using an Excel spreadsheet as a database to save the "code", "name" and "quantity" of each product. The code currently looks like this:

```
import openpyxl
import os

planilha1 = 'estoque.xlsx'
if os.path.exists(planilha1):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(planilha1)
    sheet = workbook.active
else:
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    workbook.save(planilha1)
    cabecalho = ['Código', 'Nome', 'Quantidade']
    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.append(cabecalho)

while True:
    print('=-' * 25 + '\n'
          'Estoque v1.0\n' + 
          '=-' * 25 + '\n'
    '''Selecione uma opção:
    0 - Sair e fechar o programa.
    1 - Adicionar um produto.
    2 - Remover um produto.
    3 - Pesquisar um produto específico.
    4 - Entrada de estoque.
    5 - Saída de estoque.
    ''')

    opcao = input('Opção selecionada: ')

    if opcao == '1':
        codigo = input('Digite o código do produto: ')
        nome = input('Digite o nome do produto: ')
        quantidade = int(input('Digite a quantidade: '))
        produto = [codigo, nome, quantidade]
        sheet.append(produto)
        print('Produto adicionado com sucesso!')

    elif opcao == '2':
        codigo = input('Digite o código do produto que deseja remover:')
        encontrado = False
        index = 1
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
            index += 1
            if row[0] == codigo:
                print(f'Dados a serem removidos: {row}')
                sn = input('Deseja realmente remover este produto? Esta ação não poderá ser desfeita. (S/N): ').upper()
                if sn == 'S':
                    sheet.delete_rows(index)
                    workbook.save(planilha1)
                    encontrado = True
                    print('Produto removido com sucesso!')
                    break
                elif sn == 'N':
                    break
        if row[0] != codigo:
            print('Produto não encontrado.')

    elif opcao == '3':
        codigo = input('Digite o código do produto: ')
        encontrado = False
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
            if row[0] == codigo:
                print('\n'
                    f'Código: {row[0]} || Nome: {row[1]} || Quantidade: {row[2]}'
                    '\n')
                encontrado = True
                break
        if not encontrado:
                print('Produto não encontrado.')

    elif opcao == '4':
        codigo = input('Digite o código do produto: ')
        encontrado = False
        index = 1
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
            index += 1
            if row[0] == codigo:
                linha = index
                qtd_atual = row[2]
                qtd_entrada = int(input('Digite a quantidade de entrada: '))
                row_atualizada = [row[0], row[1], qtd_atual, qtd_entrada]
                sheet.append(row_atualizada)
                sheet.delete_rows(row[0])
                encontrado = True
                print('Entrada de estoque atualizada com sucesso!')
                workbook.save(planilha1)
                sheet = workbook.active
                sheet.delete_rows(linha)
        if not encontrado:
            print('Produto não encontrado.')

    elif opcao == '5':
        codigo = input('Digite o código do produto: ')
        encontrado = False
        index = 1
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
            index += 1
            if  row[0] == codigo:
                linha = index
                qtd_atual = row[2]
                qtd_saida = int(input('Digite a quantidade de saída: '))
                if qtd_atual >= qtd_saida:
                    row_atualizada = [row[0], row[1], qtd_atual - qtd_saida]
                    sheet.append(row_atualizada)
                    sheet.delete_rows(row[0])
                    encontrado = True
                    print('Saída de estoque realizada com sucesso!')
                    workbook.save(planilha1)
                    sheet = workbook.active
                    sheet.delete_rows(linha)
                    break
                else:
                    print('Quantidade indisponível em estoque.')
                    break
        if not encontrado:
            print('Produto não encontrado.')

    elif opcao == '0':
        break
    else:
        print('Opção inválida!')
workbook.save(planilha1)
```

My problem is in relation to functions 4 and 5, which are inventory input and output, because the worksheet is immutable. Is there any way to change the values of a worksheet? I've tried what I knew and it didn't work.

I have tried to troubleshoot the problem as written in the code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).